# Which (popular) websites support mashable APIs?

Tags: api, rest, mashup

**Which popular websites out there support an HTTP based API?**

I am looking for content of general public interest (hence, Amazon's RESTful API wouldn't qualify, for example).

Some sites which I am aware of:

- [Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation)
- [Netflix](http://developer.netflix.com)
- [Upcoming](http://upcoming.yahoo.com/services/api/)
- [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/)
- [eBay](http://developer.ebay.com/products/shopping/)

*Please note that*

- Although not a direct programming question, it will help programmers find some inspiration for new projects
- A similar question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256103/some-good-example-of-restful-web-api) but didn't get many responses probably because it was very specific about being RESTful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site (with blog) "Programmable Web" collects sites, apis and howtos to create mash-ups.

You can search by programming language, protocols, wether you want something with JSON or SOAP and so on and check out existing mash-ups.

http://www.programmableweb.com/

Comment: That looks exhaustive. Thanks!